# How to configure log4j self-renewal without restarting tomcat?

Tags: java, log4j

Good day 
Please tell me - how to configure log4j - the changes made to the log4j.xml automatically accepted

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the context of the Log4J-Settings by:

```
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
ctx.reconfigure();
```

If you maybe set a new XML-Path you do:

```
System.setProperty("my.log", Settings.userStartDir + "\\log4j.xml");
```

in front of the code above.